# Apparent size of sun

Tags: everyday-life, sun

During a morning walk when I see Sun rising in the east it is quite large. Why? It is known that in the morning sun is at a greater distance than that in noon, so why it is larger? and red?

Comment: Read up about "moon illusion".

Answer (score 7):

While the sun's relative distance to you *does* change throughout the day, the change in apparent size is essentially not noticeable to the naked eye.

Radius of Earth ~3959mi

Average distance from earth to sun ~92.96 million mi

3,959mi/92,960,000mi = 0.0000641

So the change of your personal distance to the sun throughout the day is only about 0.00641% of the total distance (not really noticeable)

Actually, earth's distance to the sun changes on a much larger scale as it travels through its elliptical orbit (~91 million miles at minimum and ~94.5 million miles at maximum) and even this change is pretty much unnoticeable to the naked eye.

**The Short answer to why the sun appears larger at sunrise:** it is an optical illusion. At sunset or sunrise, the sun appears closer to the horizon and gives your brain a reference (the objects on the horizon, or the horizon itself) to base its size on. At midday your brain is given no such reference and may misjudge the sun's apparent size. The same effect can be observed with the moon.

Here's a cool trick: next time when it is a full moon out, go outside and take a piece of notebook paper and hold it at arms length. You'll notice that the moon fits entirely in one of the 3 punched holes on the side! It will fit at all times of the day - even if your brain tells you that it won't.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no universally (or even widely agreed) explanation of the moon illusion (which also effects the sun as here). The explanation you've quoted is one of the leading candidates (and the one I favor), but showing that it is definitely the correct one has proved difficult.

Comment: @dmckee It must be possible to tell if it is an illusion or not though: ie whether some atmospheric effect means the sun / moon really do subtend a greater angle at the horizon or not (I assume they don't).

Comment: Oh yes. Angular measurements are quite clear. Same size on the horizon as overhead. Using a camera is easy, as is finding a object that will just eclipse the disk overhead when held at arms length and then trying it on the horizon.